# How to extract the whole hours from a time range in Postgresql and get the duration of each extracted hour

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to database (even more to postgres), so if you can help me. I have a table something like this:

| id_interaction | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2022-06-03 12:40:10 | 2022-06-03 12:45:16 |
| 0002 | 2022-06-04 10:50:40 | 2022-06-04 11:10:12 |
| 0003 | 2022-06-04 16:30:00 | 2022-06-04 18:20:00 |
| 0004 | 2022-06-05 23:00:00 | 2022-06-06 10:30:12 |

Basically I need to create a query to get the duration doing a separation by hours, for example:

| id_interaction | start_time | end_time | hour | duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 2022-06-03 12:40:10 | 2022-06-03 12:45:16 | 12:00:00 | 00:05:06 |
| 0002 | 2022-06-04 10:50:40 | 2022-06-04 11:10:12 | 10:00:00 | 00:09:20 |
| 0002 | 2022-06-04 10:50:40 | 2022-06-04 11:10:12 | 11:00:00 | 00:10:12 |
| 0003 | 2022-06-04 16:30:00 | 2022-06-04 18:20:00 | 16:00:00 | 00:30:00 |
| 0003 | 2022-06-04 16:30:00 | 2022-06-04 18:20:00 | 17:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 0003 | 2022-06-04 16:30:00 | 2022-06-04 18:20:00 | 18:00:00 | 00:20:00 |
| 0004 | 2022-06-05 23:00:00 | 2022-06-06 03:30:12 | 23:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 0004 | 2022-06-05 23:00:00 | 2022-06-06 03:30:12 | 24:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 0004 | 2022-06-05 23:00:00 | 2022-06-06 03:30:12 | 01:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 0004 | 2022-06-05 23:00:00 | 2022-06-06 03:30:12 | 02:00:00 | 01:00:00 |
| 0004 | 2022-06-05 23:00:00 | 2022-06-06 03:30:12 | 03:00:00 | 00:30:12 |

I need all the hours from start to finish. For example: if an id starts at 17:10 and ends at 19:00, I need the duration of 17:00, 18:00 and 19:00

Comment: I updated my answer re-reading your question after the edits and taking a closer look at your data. Is it a desired effect that you're getting 45:06 duration between 12:40:10 and 12:45:16 for `id_interacao='0001'`? If tempo_final is an exact, round hour, do you want a record listing that as a `hora` with 00:00:00 in `duracao` ?

Comment: I was wrong. It was 00:05:06 (end_time - start_time) within 12:00.

Comment: In that case my [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74113465/5298879) should fit your criteria. How about if `tempo_final` is an exact, round hour, like 12:00:00 - do you want a record listing that as a `hora` with 00:00:00 in `duracao`, or should that be skipped?

Comment: In that case when the end time is round it can be skipped

Comment: It can be achieved with a simple `where duracao<>'0'::interval` - I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I will check here

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the duration in each whole hour interval overlapped by your data, this can be achieved by rounding timestamps using [date_trunc()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), using [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to move around the intervals and casting between [time, interval and timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

```sql
create or replace function hours_crossed(starts timestamp,ends timestamp) 
  returns integer 
  language sql as '
select case 
    when date_trunc(''hour'',starts)=date_trunc(''hour'',ends)
        then 0
    when date_trunc(''hour'',starts)=starts
        then floor(extract(''epoch'' from ends-starts)::numeric/60.0/60.0)
    else floor(extract(''epoch'' from ends-starts)::numeric/60.0/60.0) +1
        end';

select * from (
    select 
        id_interacao,
        tempo_inicial,
        tempo_final,
        to_char(hora, 'HH24:00')::time as hora,
        least(tempo_final, hora + '1 hour'::interval)
            - greatest(tempo_inicial, hora) 
                as duracao
    from (select  
            *,
            date_trunc('hour',tempo_inicial)
                + (generate_series(0, hours_crossed(tempo_inicial,tempo_final))::text||' hours')::interval
                    as hora
          from test_times 
          ) a
      ) a
where duracao<>'0'::interval;
```

This also fixes your first entry that lasts 5 minutes but shows as 45.
You'll need to decide how you want to handle zero-length intervals and ones that end on an exact hour - I added a condition to skip them. [Here's a working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/DczUJPbs).